# How to install QGIS on Linux NAS using IPKG

Tags: qgis, installation

I have a Linux -Based NAS that I want to install QGIS onto.
Since I am administering through a web interface from a Windows based PC, how can I install QGIS?
Is there a way maybe through IPKG?
Or any other solutions?
I am almost ignorant of native Linux use.

Comment: Are you going to use the NAS to host a QGIS server?  Or are you trying to install the desktop binaries to the NAS?

Comment: What is remote operating system?

Comment: I would like to use the NAS as a QGIS server. I imagine it is accessible from a web interface?

My remote operating system is Windows Vista / XP

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to leave a comment, but not enough karma.
This is what I'm currently investigating:

- Synology diskstation DS215j (ARM 7 -- armhf processor) NAS
- Synocommunity package installer: synocommunity.com
- Devian Chroot installation Package: https://github.com/SynoCommunity/spksrc/wiki/Debian-Chroot
- https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&arch=armhf&searchon=names&keywords=gdal

The above successfully installed python3 with GDAL support on a NAS running Linux (Synology NAS with Debian Chroot)

However, I'm confused as to what you're attempting to do, as QGIS is usually a client that interfaces with GIS data.

Comment: What I was WONDERING is whether I can use the NAS to run QGIS Server.

In this case, if there is a ipkg installation solution because I don't have any Linux skills to set it up otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Intel based NAS, you could use Docker: http://www.jinkit.com/docker-on-synology/

Once you have Docker, you can get a QGIS Server image easily: https://github.com/kartoza/docker-qgis-server